# How to set a property in ruby datamapper that is a function of another property of the same object?

Tags: ruby, properties, datamapper

I want to add two new properties to a ruby datamapper model, one that is a date cast of a timestamp property and another that is a value from another object connected through a unique key.

So for the first case I have 
    property :date, DateTime

and I want to add another
    property :date_date, Date
that by default will be equal to date.to_date

Comment: Don't put too much information in the title. The title should just give a summary. Write the elaborated question in the main text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see the docs: https://datamapper.org/docs/properties.html

Specifically the sections on "Available Types" and "Setting default values".

You can do it like this:

```
property :date_date, Date, default: -> do |obj, prop|
  obj.date.to_date
end
```

You can alternatively set it through a callback (https://datamapper.org/docs/callbacks.html), for example:

```
property :date_date, Date

before_save :set_date_date

def set_date_date
  self.date_date = date.to_date
end
```

Note it works basically the same way in Rails' ActiveRecord as well.